# Handling special characters in python

Tags: python, character

I have this string:

```
self.assertEquals(ex.user_message,
                              '''Equalum agent has returned the following error:\nDirectory "{}" doesnt exist.'''
                              .format(agent_stream['directory']))
```

and I want to change it to:

```
self.assertEquals(ex.user_message,
                                  '''Equalum agent has returned the following error:\nDirectory "{}" doesn't exist.'''
                                  .format(agent_stream['directory']))
```

How can I write doesn't instead of doesnt in python?

Erez

Comment: instead of the `'''` try `"`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the second code snippet...

Comment: My first comment `doesn't` work instead of `"` it needs to be `"""`. but as @Rawing says - your example works too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use \’ to escape single quotes like "doesn\'t" for example. [http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/escapes.html](http://python%20escape%20characters)